# Brand new SonarQube 5.3 install crashing while doing issue differential

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Here is what I have done so far;

- Installed sonarqube 5.3
- Pointed SQ 5.3 at an empty sonar database with a valid sonar user
- Run an analysis on a project
- Run an analysis on the project again

When I look at the project page after the second analysis and there are new issues, I click the link that says "30 new issues" to show me the recently introduced issues. It builds a URL something like this:

http://sonar-server:9000/component_issues?id=myproject#resolved=false|createdAfter=2016-07-21T18%3A20%3A08%2B0000

But then I get large pink Elasticsearch error, which boils down to this:

```
NumberFormatException[For input string: "GMT+00"];
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:237) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$1.onFailure(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:183) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
...
```

The only offending snippet of the JSON I can see that contains that string looks like this:

```
"createdAt": {"date_histogram":
{"field":"issueCreatedAt",  
"interval":"1d",
"min_doc_count":0,
"pre_zone":"GMT+00:00",
"post_zone":"GMT+00:00",
"format":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

Someone appears to have had a very similar issue recently, but did not get an answer: [sonarqube 5.x differential views KO (JSON parsing exception)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596110/sonarqube-5-x-differential-views-ko-json-parsing-exception)

I tried the solution from that issue - forcing a user.timezone - but even if I put it into wrapper.conf in the "don't mess with this" section as an additional property, it is not passed to the underlying Java processes (when I check with ps -ef | grep java).

I googled, stackoverflow-searched, [searched the google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sonarqube/numberformatexception) and [Sonarqube-JIRA](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/COBOL-1306?jql=text%20~%20numberformatexception%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC) searched for things like NumberFormatException sonarqube, etc. I am at a loss. This is a brand new install of SQ 5.3, onto a machine whose time zone is set to GMT.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Why not using SonarQube 5.6 LTS if it is brand new?

Comment: Agree with @JeroenHeier, there's no reason to install a SQ 5.3 while the 5.6 LTS version (= the most stable version) is available.

Comment: I would love to but we need MySQL 5.6 or greater to do that. It's a long story... So, is this a known bug in 5.3 or something?